# Moving CVS modules to right GIT item

Tags: git, cvs, migrate

Have CVS repository for an application, with several modules:

- application code

  documentation

  unit test scripts.

I need to plan how to migrate to git.
I would like help to understand if creating one repository for each module is a good option.

regards

Answer (score 1):

I think  that all those modules should be under one repository, because they are useless each without other.

Comment: In my case is not really true that >>> they are useless each without other. Normally I work only with application code i.e get only this module not others.

Answer (score 0):

almost all of the git repository that I have seen contain all of the modules that you counted.
I don't see any reason to create multiple repositories.

This guide can help you:
[CVS to git Transition Guide](http://www.chem.helsinki.fi/~jonas/git_guides/HTML/CVS2git/)

Comment: I've read this document before asking, but was not able to find a clear indication of how to go.